# How can I get last only if more than one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails I have this:

```
page_classes.split(/\s/).last
```

Sometimes page_classes doesn't contain any whitespace and I get the error:

```
undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I get the last unless there is only one?

Comment: I think your title is miss-leading. You error is occurring with none, not one.

Comment: I dont get the error you reported.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
page_classes.split(/\s/).try(:last)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: can you put some example. see this http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try. even if you do nil.try(:last) it will not crash and if [1,2,3].try(:last) it will return 3

Comment: i also tested on this "john robbert".split(/\s/).try(:last) it returned "robert"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about your page_classes object.

```
page_classes.split("\s").last
```

Calling `.last` will ALWAYS work with an array (even empty). If you have probems, it means your `page_classes` object is nil or not a string that can be processed by `split()`.